# IMPDP only metadata into existing table ORACLE

Tags: database, oracle, impdp, expdp

I'm trying to import just content METADATA into an existing database with same SCHEMA and tables.

I just want to update the tables metadata.

I'm using

```
expdp user/pass SCHEMAS=userschema dumpfile=export:bbdd.dmp version=10.2 content= METADATA_ONLY
```

And then I tried to use

```
impdp user/pass dumpfile=export:bbdd.dmp TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=APPEND
```

But I'm facing "Data will be appended but all dependent metadata will be skipped", I just want to import the metadata.

Any help will be very appreciate

BTW. I'm exporting from Oracle 11g database to Oracle 10g database.

Comment: This error mean there are existing on the target database. `TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=APPEND` option will append rows to the existing table.If you just want the meta data then can use other options `TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION={SKIP | APPEND | TRUNCATE | REPLACE} `.

Comment: To do this you have to drop your existing schema or existing objects and then import the new objects with updated metadata. You can't update metadata without losing your content of tables. :)

Comment: Should i drop the table data content first ?? I want to preserve data and just update metadata. Its possible export in 2 files, one for data and one for metadata and then import first metadata with TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION =REPLACE and then import just data ?